# Can't call PHP function multiple times

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to fix my previous problem with an extra query.

However, when I am trying to make multiple calls to my PHP function it just shows the first one and not both.

Code:

```
<?php function test($colour)
{

    $pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb","teun",""); // or use a global one 
    //$pdo = $GLOBALS['pdo'];
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE cat_id = :cat_id AND thread_date=(
    SELECT max(thread_date) FROM threads
    )");
 $sth->bindParam(':cat_id', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
 $sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();
echo $result ["thread_name"];
}
?>
```

(yes, I know this is unsafe but I want to achieve my thing first before I work on the safe part).

I call it using test `($row['extra_cat_id'])`

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "it just shows the first one and not both.?" What is your desired output? Also for the record, that query is safe. "(yes, I know this is unsafe " is not correct.

Comment: That I can call the function only one time, even while it should work with multiple calls.

Comment: Such as `test($row['extra_cat_id']); test($row['extra_cat_id']);` ?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from calling the function twice in that manor so I'm pretty sure your problem is that your query returns 0 results for one of the calls. Add `var_dump($sth->rowCount());` before `$sth->execute();` and see what it returns.

Comment: I got it working by replacing the 'AND' with the 'WHERE', but somehow it doesn't allow me same thread_date in database. When I make a new row in it with the same thread_date as another row, it prints the first row out.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch()` only fetches 1 row, see [PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Either iterate using `fetch()` to fetch 1 by 1, or use the `fetchAll()` method to fetch all results, see [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)